# Ways to intercept key presses in a WPF app natively

Tags: .net, wpf, keypress

What's the best method for intercepting key presses and handling them in a WPF app, avoiding the control with focus getting the keypress?

I need the application to handle a sequence of key presses (including arrow keys) and avoid a control with focus (i.e. Treeview) getting the key press events.  I've seen ways of doing this with interop but was hoping there was support for this natively within a WPF application?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can attach to the [PreviewKeyDown](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.previewkeydown.aspx) event of the root element in your application, which is typically a Window. If you set e.Handled to true, then you will normally prevent anything else from getting the PreviewKeyDown or the KeyDown event.

In addition, you may need to handle the [PreviewTextInput](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.previewtextinput.aspx) event, as this is what text boxes or other editors normally use.